# Maven cannot compile project with dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem. I created 2 maven projects and copied both the folders to my Ubuntu server. When I want to `mvn package` program A, which has included the dependency of project B (Simulator):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.simulator</groupId>
  <artifactId>simulator</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

It says:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hatop: Could not resolve dependencies                                                                             for project com.hatop:hatop:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.simula                                                                            tor:simulator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o                                                                            n project hatop: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.hatop:hatop:jar:                                                                            1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.simulator:simulator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDepend                                                                            encies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolvePr                                                                            ojectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreRes                                                                            olved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded                                                                            Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt                                                                            arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso                                                                            rImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho                                                                            dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche                                                                            r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2                                                                            25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc                                                                            her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347                                                                            )
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res                                                                            olve dependencies for project com.hatop:hatop:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find a                                                                            rtifact com.simulator:simulator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (Defa                                                                            ultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDepend                                                                            encies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolvePr                                                                            ojectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreRes                                                                            olved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded                                                                            Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt                                                                            arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso                                                                            rImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho                                                                            dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche                                                                            r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2                                                                            25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc                                                                            her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347                                                                            )
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could no                                                                            t find artifact com.simulator:simulator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependenc                                                                            ies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:357)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (Defa                                                                            ultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDepend                                                                            encies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolvePr                                                                            ojectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreRes                                                                            olved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded                                                                            Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt                                                                            arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso                                                                            rImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho                                                                            dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche                                                                            r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2                                                                            25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc                                                                            her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347                                                                            )
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not                                                                             find artifact com.simulator:simulator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (Default                                                                            ArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts                                                                             (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependenc                                                                            ies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (Defa                                                                            ultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDepend                                                                            encies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolvePr                                                                            ojectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreRes                                                                            olved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded                                                                            Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt                                                                            arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso                                                                            rImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho                                                                            dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche                                                                            r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2                                                                            25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc                                                                            her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347                                                                            )
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find                                                                             artifact com.simulator:simulator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (Default                                                                            ArtifactResolver.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts                                                                             (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependenc                                                                            ies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (Defa                                                                            ultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDepend                                                                            encies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolvePr                                                                            ojectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreRes                                                                            olved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja                                                                            va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (                                                                            LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded                                                                            Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt                                                                            arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso                                                                            rImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho                                                                            dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche                                                                            r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2                                                                            25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc                                                                            her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347                                                                            )
```

I have already packaged the simulator project so there is a `.jar` file in the target folder of that package. Running it in Visual Code on my windows desktop works fine and the project get's packaged. What is causing this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `mvn install` on the dependency first.

Answer (score 1):

Running `mvn package` only generates the JAR in the `target` folder on this project.

However, to be able to use this JAR through dependency mechanism on another project you need to put in a place where Maven expects it: it's called a Maven repository.

You have one local Maven repository in `$HOME/.m2/repository` for instance. There are also remote repositories (Maven Central) where public libraries are available for instance.

So you have to put the JAR file of your project into a repository.

How to do that?

**To publish it to your local repository, you can just run `mvn install` instead of `mvn package`.**